# error: no match for 'operator=' in 'iter = ((const FHlist<Employee>*)theList)->FHlist<Object>::begin [with Object = Employee]()'

Tags: c++

Im doing a hashing function, and it wont compile, I copied the function below.
Thank you for your help, and excuse my english

```
template <class Object>
bool FHhashSC<Object>::contains(const Object & x) const
{
   const FHlist<Object> &theList = mLists[myHash(x)];
   typename FHlist<Object>::iterator iter;

   for (iter = theList.begin(); iter != theList.end(); iter++)
      if (*iter == x)
         return true;

   // not found
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Please indicate what won't compile, and what the error was.

Comment: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'iter = ((const FHlist<Employee>*)theList)->FHlist<Object>::begin [with Object = Employee]()'

Comment: in the line: for (iter = theList.begin(); iter != theList.end(); iter++)

Answer (score 2):

You should use const_iterator because theList is a constant object.

Comment: like this: typename FHlist<Object>::const_iterator iter;??

Comment: Yes, if theList is a some standard container that has iterator and const_iterator.